# Problema al instalar librerias de Python

Tags: python, cmd, pip, librería, modulos

Buenas mañanas, tardas o noches

Estoy intentando instalar una librería utilizando el comando -pip install convert-to-time- que encontré en pypi -**https://pypi.org/project/convert-to-time/#description**- para convertir segundos a minutos  y me salen los siguiente error en la consola:

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement convert-to-time (from versions: none)**

**ERROR: No matching distribution found for convert-to-time**

Mi versión de Python es la 3.10.4 y tengo el pip actualizado hace unos minutos usando el comando -python -m pip install --upgrade pip-

Aclaro esto ultimo porque buscando posibles soluciones al problema, me tope con varias respuestas que hacían alusión a que el problema se solucionaba  actualizando tanto Python como el propio pip. En mi caso particular es no es el problema porque actualice ambas cosas y el problema persiste

Mas allá de poder o no instalar el paquete en cuestión, mi duda radica en que significan los carteles de error.

Por lo que puedo intuir, luego de investigar un rato, ese error se debe a que el paquete que quiero instalar, no es compatible con la versión que tengo de Python o directamente es un paquete desactualizado y obsoleto que ya no esta en uso y no hay otra solución mas que buscar otro paquete y ya

De todos modos me gustaría sacarme la duda completamente porque soy nuevo en la programación, quiero aprender a buscar módulos de manera rápida y eficiente y para eso quiero ser capaz de determinar de manera rápida que módulos son obsoletos para seguir buscando sin reparar en ellos

Desde ya muchas gracias y happy coding

Comment: No se si seamos los únicos con el mismo problema. Pero yo tampoco puedo instalar el modulo usando `pip install convert-to-time`. Lo que me llama la atención es que el link al repositorio de GitHub está caído. Yo tengo Python 3.9.7 y el pip actualizado. Intentar descargar manualmente el whl e intentar instalarlo con el comando `pip install convert_to_time-0.0.1-py2-none-any.whl` arroja el siguiente error: `ERROR: convert_to_time-0.0.1-py2-none-any.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`. Supongo que el modulo fue abandonado hace tiempo.

Comment: Por curiosidad (no es obligatorio que me respondas esto) por que estas buscando estos modulos (convert-to-time y seconds)?

Comment: Por cierto, perdón por no responder a tu duda puntual, no se tanto de como funciona pypi. De hecho, es la primera vez que me encuentro con que una pagina de pypi que dice que un modulo existe y que no funcione el pip install.

Comment: @DanteS. Te pongo en contexto ya que venís de la pregunte anterior jaja. Estoy resolviendo ejercicios de lógica de programación de una pagina que encontré -https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/ejercicios/ej-variables.html- y si bien puedo resolverlos sin ayuda de ningún paquete, me di a la tarea de buscar alguno que me ayudara para empezar a practicar como se usan las librerías.
Por lo que veo esta desicion no es del todo erronea porque no dejo de encontrar problemas y trabas desde que empeze xD

Comment: @DanteS. Yo tengo la teoría de que esos errores se deben a que el modulo en si esta desactualizado o que simplemente no es compatible con la ultima version de python, pero me gustaria estar 100% seguro asi si la proxima vez me sale un error similar, no pierdo tiempo, busco directamente otro y listo

Comment: Me gusta esa pasión por aprender c: Por cierto, suerte con tu objetivo! Esperemos a que alguien que sepa más del tema responda tu pregunta

Comment: Un poco desactualizado está. El ultimo cambio que le hicieron fue hace casi 4 años.

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias Bro! Estoy empezando en esto y de a poco me apasiona el tema. Yo creo que me voy a declinar (aunque sea por ahora) por la teoría de que no me anda porque es un proyecto abandonado hace tiempo (el echo de que no tenga ninguna descripción en la pagina de PYPI apoya esta teoría )

Comment: @DanteS. Como hago para hablarte por chat? Me gustaria preguntarte un par de cosas ya que ambos estamos en el mundo de python

Comment: De nada! Hay modulos que no tienen ninguna descripción y aun así funcionan (tienen descripciones en la pagina principal, que habitualmente es un repositorio de Github). Ahora busco la forma de que hablemos por chat, asi no ocupamos la sección de comentarios. En realidad, los comentarios no fueron hechos para socializar, pero esa regla siempre me pareció muy "fria".

Comment: Voté una pregunta para que puedas hablar en el chat c: Quieres unirte a nuestro chat y luego iniciamos una conversación privada? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol Avisame cuando estés. En poco me voy a dormir.

Comment: @DanteS. Dale dale! Me gustaria unirme a ese chat. De todos modos lo hacemos mañana, anda a dormir tranca. Creo que no puedo hablar en el chat porque necesito una reputacion de 20 como minimo  ._.

Comment: Hola, ya estoy de vuelta! Por eso voté una de tus preguntas. Para que tengas más reputación y puedas hablar por el chat. Te espero allá! Recuerda mencionarme como @Dantes. para que me llegue la notificación!

Comment: @DanteS. Ya te hable